# Finding results using the EF4 in a table where they don't exist or don't match a value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 tables

I have 3 stores each creating transactions and inserting them into the transaction table with their own store ID.
I want to be able to query the transaction table for all transactions where they are yet to be inserted into the TransactionMapping Table with the storeID that is making the search

e.g.

TransactionTable

[image: Transaction Table]

MappingTable

[image: Mapping Table]

I want to get all transaction information from Transaction where the matching TransactionId within TransactionMapping Table don't contain the storeID from the store calling the query.

As you can see there are 4 transactions added to the transaction table for stores 1 & 2.

Looking at the mapping table both stores 1 & 2 have all transactions mapped however store 3 has nothing mapped.

How do I write the linq query to return the 4 records within the transaction table for store 3?

Any assistance in what is I would imagine is a straight forward query for someone not struggling on a Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out. Thought I would post how I did it in case someone else had the same problem

```
 var query = (from a in ctx.TransactionTable
              from b in ctx.MappingTable.Where(x => x.TransactionId== a.TransactionId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where a.StoreID!=storeID
                     select new
                               {
                                  Transactions = a,
                                  Mapping = b
                               }).ToList();
```